# Tools for Embedded, Desktop and Mobile Performance Testing

Tags: performance-testing, mobile, desktop-application, embedded, test-tools

I need to validate about 30 performance requirements on two desktop applications (one made using WPF, and other made using VCL) and about 10 performance requirements on embedded system (a tablet with our own OS running an application) and also a smartphone that runs our app

However, I'm kind of struggling to find a tool that fit in requirments like:

- The application must respond to user input in less than 0.1 second
- The function ABC shall be performed in less than 3 seconds
- A new income message shall be displayed in less than 0.2 seconds

The tool might be able to:

- mark when the action began (e.g. click on "Add new user buton")
- mark when its finished (e.g. opened the form to add a new user)
- and give me back the amount of time taken to perform the action.
- Alson on smartphone only, I shall have a way to see a graph over time on RAM, CPU, memory and Network using